# Node launcher for testem using jasmine framework

Tags: testing, jasmine, testem

I am testing nodejs backend code with [jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/node.html) and trying to set up [testem](https://github.com/testem/testem).
My `testem.json`:

```
{
    "framework": "jasmine",
    "launchers": {
        "Node": {
            "command": "jasmine"
        }
    },
    "launch_in_dev": [
        "Node"
    ]
}
```

When i run `testem` i see proper jasmine output, no problems here, it says:

```
Started
....


4 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.024 seconds
```

But seems like jasmine reporter doesn't report testem about total/passed/failed.
If just shows: [image]

How do i fix that?